# Yearweek returns different results

Tags: mysql

Why are the YEARWEEKs of the both following dates different? 
Both dates (2018-12-29 AND 2018-12-30) are in the same week?

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-12-29 20:10:00'); = 201851
SELECT CURDATE(); = 2018-12-30
SELECT YEARWEEK(CURDATE()); = 201852
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default mode of operation of [`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) and [`WEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) is set by the [`default_week_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format) system variable, which defaults to 0, in which mode weeks are assumed to start on Sunday. To do your computation based on weeks starting on Monday (so that 2018-12-29 and 2018-12-30 are in the same week), use one of the modes described in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) which supports that (1, 3, 5 and 7). So for example

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-12-29 20:10:00', 1), YEARWEEK('2018-12-30', 1)
```

Output:

```
201852    201852
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-01-06'); returns 201753 -- saturday
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-01-07'); returns 201801 -- sunday
```

while `2018-01-06` seems to return `201801`.

*returns the year and week number (a number from 0 to 53) for a given date, looks for whole(completed) weeks which end with each saturdays. Iterates to the next value at upcoming sundays*

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I get the same "week-value" for both dates?